# Detecting button press in CardAction BotBuilder

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

So within a carousel I have `builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'relatedStuff', 'Related stuff'),`

and i've been doing a match to match once this is selected and handle a new dialog like so:

```
bot.dialog('relatedStuff', (session, args, next) => {
  // console.log(session, '<<<<<< SESSION');
  session.endDialog('This is a simple bot that collects a name and age.');
}).triggerAction({
  matches: /^relatedStuff$/,
  onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
    session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
  },
});
```

How can I identify what's being selected rather than doing a match?

So for example,

`builder.CardAction.imBack(session, data.name, 'Related events'),` and do a dialog that says `if (data.name === 'something) { do something.. }`

I can't find anything in the docs that tells me how to identify what's been selected if I don't know the value beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`session.message.text` will contain the value of the button pressed. You should check for the value there.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/index.js#L15-L37) is an example of how this works.